# How many roots does the polynomial $p(z) = z^8 + 3z^7 + 6z^2 + 1$ have inside the annulus $1 < |z| < 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

How many roots does the polynomial $p(z) = z^8 + 3z^7 + 6z^2 + 1$ have inside the annulus $1 < |z| < 2$?

I know I can use Rouche's Theorem. I'm just not sure how. It states that $|f(z) − g(z)| < |f(z)|$ where $f(z)$ is the given polynomial and we choose $g(z)$. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General approach, you use Rouche theorem to count the number ofroots inside the circles of radius $1$ and $2$ and by substracting this quantity, you obtain the number of roots in the annulus.

How to apply Rouches theorem to find the number of roots in the circle of radius $1$. You can chose $f(z)=6z^2$ and $g(z)=z^8+3z^7+1$. On the considerd contour we have : $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$. So $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of roots inside the contour counting multiplicity. So $p$ has $2$ roots in the circle of radius $1$.

I will let you do the same with the circle of radius $2$.

Comment: I did it and it says that there are $8$ zeros in the circle of radius $2$. So I get $8-2=6$, but I think that it is wrong.

Comment: Hmm for the circle of radius $2$ I used $f=3z^7$, so I found $7$ zeros in this circle and so $5$ zeros in the annulus.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! How does one know which $f$ to choose?

Comment: Well I try to pick $f$ as a monome, and test with triangular inequality which one will verify $|g|<|f|$. For example here I knew that for $|z|=2$, I would have $|3z^7|>|z^8|$ so I knew it would be a good idea to try $f=3z^7$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you : )

Comment: Using $z=2w$ to get back to the unit circle, $f(2w)=256z^8+384w^7+24w^2+1$ shows clearly that the dominant term is the 7th degree one.

Answer (score -3):

I think total zeros are 7-2=5 inside the annulus. Because, for |z|<1: 2 roots and |z|<2: 7 roots. Is it ok.

Comment: Apart from the subtraction $7-2=5$, I don't see any mathematical reasoning to follow.  Surely there is more to the problem of locating roots inside/outside the annulus?  This question has been around for a couple of years and already had an Accepted Answer, so it is important to read the previous response in order to highlight what new information you are adding.